# Subfigures not labeled as a) b) etc

Tags: subfloats

[image]

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{subfigure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{images/XCO2.PNG}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{images/YCO2.PNG}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{}
\label{}
\end{figure}
```

I have used this code for subfigures but the subfigures are not labeled as a), b) etc. If I add a caption to the subfigure, each subfigure is changed to a main figure. I use subcaption package

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! You not add caption to `\subfigure`. Also it seems that you use obsolete `subfigure` package. It is replaced by `subfig` or even beter use `subcaption` package. For further help, please extend your code fragment to complete small document with your figure.

Comment: @Zarko `subfig` is also obsolete. Its description on CTAN refers to `subcaption` as the current package.

Comment: @Miyase, on CTAn is not mentioned that is obsolete (what is for subfigure). However, is mentioned that "The functionality of the package is provided by the (more recent still) subcaption package." This can be understand, that better than `subfig` is package `subcaption` which from version 1.3 further also support `\subfloat` command before defined only in `subfig`.

Comment: @Zarko You may be right, but for me "a newer package integrates the same features and more" is almost the textbook definition of obsolete.

Comment: @Miyase, not really. Some uptodate package still require to use `subfig` due to incompatibility with `caption` and `subcaption` packages. So I concluded that on CTAN are aware and not yet declare `subfig` obsolete ;-)

Comment: Any news? Does my answer solve your problem=

Comment: @zarco Yes, I used subcaption package and the problem was solved. Thank you

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because is solved by comments, as OP said.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[skip=0.5ex, belowskip=1ex,
            labelformat=brace,      % <---
            ]{subcaption}


\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[!ht]
\begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{images/XCO2.PNG}
    \caption{ first subfigure}
\end{subfigure}

\medskip
\begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{images/YCO2.PNG}
    \caption{second subfigure}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Main caption}
\label{fig:?}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comparison my MWE with your code fragment show the following differences:

- defined is document preamble
- `subcaption` settings  define subfigure captions' labels as `a)`, `b=` ...
- added is width of subfigures
- added are `caption`s to subfigures
- removed are `centering` in subfigures (since their width is equal to text width)
- Remark: never use `[h]` placement. I can make troubles. Give to LateX some more option/freedom for figure placement. For example with `[ht]` or `[htbp]`.

[image]